# Google chrome Firebug Lite not working

Tags: google-chrome, firebug

I have updated version of Google chrome with installed Firebug Lite on two computers and both are broken. 
Tried to re-install and nothing.
Used Googles own inspector to check firebug lite and it gets back the following error when Inspect button is clicked

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined chrome-extension://bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench/firebug-lite.js:2562
17

The site that I want to inspect is on https but that could not be it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should report a bug to Firebug.